# Managing Conflicting Proto File Packages and Import Paths in Go

Tags: go, import, protobuf-go

I have two proto files in the same folder.

Because of the history, **a.proto**'s package name is different from **b.proto**. But they have **a same message variable**. Meanwhile, we can not change the defination because if we do this, there are too many files we need to change.

Firstly, the a.proto

```
package service_interface;
option go_package = "pb_gen/service";

message point {
    required uint32 x = 1;
    required uint32 y = 2;
}

message view {
    required uint32 x = 1;
    required uint32 y = 2;
}
```

then b.proto

```
import "a.proto";
package mydemo;
option go_package = "pb_gen/mydemo";

message point {
    required uint32 x = 1;
    required uint32 y = 2;
}
message bible {
    required service_interface.view v = 1;
}
```

And I run the command to generate the **pb.go** files, **no errors**.
But when I import these two protos into my golang files,

```
import (
    "my/demo-api/pb_gen/mydemo"
)
```

it tells me

```
 package pb_gen/mydemo is not in GOROOT
```

I have set **go.mod**, looks like

```
module my/demo-api
```

What is the problem? Or is there a better way to manage these two proto files?

Comment: is the content you mentioned in go.mod is all of it ? if so i recommend removing it and instead run `go mod init`

Comment: @mooga yes. go.mod contains all.

Comment: can you run `go mod tidy` or remove and go.mod and run `go mod init`

Comment: @mooga I did it but the generated **go.mod** looks the same as before

Comment: so it has the same complain ? can you show how you import the 2 packages ?

Comment: yes, it has the same complain. these 2 packages are **my/demo-api/pb_gen/mydemo** and **my/demo-api/pb_gen/service**